# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS : Whatever I am installing using pip3, it is giving a warning saying, add /home/username/.local/bin to path

Tags: bashrc, pip, 20.04

I am asking this question because I was facing the same issue and could not find a complete solution so here it is.
Steps to follow :
1. Open Files app, go to home.
2. Open .bashrc file using text editor (hit ctrl+H if .bashrc file is not seen)
3. Scroll all the way to the end and type this -

```
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

And save the file.
4. Now open the terminal and type -

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

5. You can either use option 4 or just restart your computer.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please don't put the answer within your question. Press the write your own answer button

Comment: Yeah, just post the question and separately write an answer to your own question. Then, you can accept your answer as the preferred solution after a few days to give other people the chance to also provide answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path)

Answer (score 0):

I am asking this question because I was facing the same issue and could not find a complete solution so here it is.
Steps to follow :
1. Open Files app, go to home.
2. Open .bashrc file using text editor (hit ctrl+H if .bashrc file is not seen)
3. Scroll all the way to the end and type this -

```
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

And save the file.
4. Now open the terminal and type -

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

5. You can either use option 4 or just restart your computer.